# Excel/VBA: Passing a single cell as argument

Tags: vba, excel

I want to make my custom VBA function accept only a single-cell argument. What is the rightway of doing it:

- pass `myCell as Cell`

or:

- pass `myRange as Range` and get (how?) the left-upper cell by default?

Comment: Can you show the function as well.. you can add in `Myfunction(ByRef myCell as Range)` as the parameter

Comment: Actually, as if often happens, solution comes up after asking the question: `topLeftValue = myRange.Cells(1, 1).Value`

Comment: is the following answer's validation that you are looking for?

Comment: I was searching for a swifty way for setting a default value. My above comment contains an answer that works best for me. Will add it as my own answer. Thanks anyway for the effort. But BTW: what's the purpose of ByRef - you meant to alter the param?

Comment: You don't provide the definition of topLeftValue though. It's best always to show your code instaed of a line. I missed out the `default` part though, if you had emphasized that you want to take first cell of any range then yes, would have been clearer.

Comment: Arthur, If you want to know the difference between byRef and byVal, check my reply here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339811/function-arguments-vba/11341235#11341235  I illustrated with a basic example.

Comment: Thanks, I have used RealStudio, PHP where I found out the difference, but I haven't spotted in your code any attempt to alter the argument, hence the question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you select more than one cell the function will exit:

```
Function AcceptOneCell(rng As Range)

If (rng.Cells.Count > 1) Then
    AcceptOneCell = "Only allow 1 cell"
    Exit Function
End If

    ' your code here

End Function
```

Comment: so can i call this function like this----> AcceptOneCell( Cells(1,1))       (will that work?

Comment: yes you can. Good also to define what sheet the cell (Range) is coming from: Sheet1.Cells(1,1) for example.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming your user will enter a range with multiple columns and rows, you can do the following check to exit the function if that's what you meant in the question...

```
Function myFunction(ByRef myCell as Range) as SomeDataType_of_your_choice
Dim numRow as Long, numCol as Long

numRow = myCell.Columns.Count 
numCol = myCell.Rows.Count 

If numRow > 1 or numCol > 1 Then
   MsgBox "Only one cell is accepted"
   Exit Function    
Else
   '-- do other stuff you want to do here
End If
End Function
```

Comment: + 1 for giving what the OP asked

Answer (score 4):

```
topLeftValue = myRange.Cells(1, 1).Value
```

Answer (score 1):

I've added the below range checks within my own functions/subs, in order to proceed even if a range of > 1 cell is passed. This forces the selection of the top-left-most cell in the case a range with multiple cells is passed to the function. This is an alternative path to the other answers, which end the current function instead.

```
Sub DoSomethingWithCells(StartCell As Range)
'Ensure that only the first cell of range is selected

If (StartCell.Cells.Count > 1) Then
    'Select only the first cell
    StartCell = StartCell.Cells(1, 1).Address
End If

'Do whatever you need to do here

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
numRow = myCell.Columns.Count 

numCol = myCell.Rows.Count
```

Should be

```
numColum = myCell.Columns.Count 

numRow = myCell.Rows.Count
```